# error: use of moved value res in Rust

Tags: rust

What's up with this code:

```
fn method1(a: &str) -> (String, String) {
  let res = method2(a);
  (res.val0(), res.val1())
}
```

The error is:

```
error: use of moved value res
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like that `method2()` returns a non-copyable object, while `val0()` and `val1()` methods take their target by value:

```
struct SomeType { ... }

impl SomeType {
    fn val0(self) -> String { ... }
    fn val1(self) -> String { ... }
}

fn method2(a: &str) -> SomeType { ... }

fn method1(a: &str) -> (String, String) {
    let res = method2(a);
    (res.val0(), res.val1())
}
```

Because `SomeType` is not automatically copyable, it will be moved into methods which take it by value, but you are trying to do it *twice*, which is unsound, and the compiler reports "use of moved value" error.

If you can't change `SomeType` and it only has `val0()` and `val1()` methods, does not have public fields  and does not implement `Clone`. then you're out of luck. You will be able only to get the result of either `val0()` or `val1()` method, but not both.

If `SomeType` also has methods which return references, like this:

```
impl SomeType {
    fn ref0(&self) -> &String { ... }
    fn ref1(&self) -> &String { ... }
}
```

(`&str` instead of `&String` is fine too)
then you can clone the strings:

```
let res = method2(a);
(res.ref0().clone(), res.ref1().clone())
```

Even better if `SomeType` provides some kind of destructuring, for example:

```
impl SomeType {
    fn into_tuple(self) -> (String, String) { ... }
}
```

Then it is straightforward:

```
method2(a).into_tuple()
```

If `SomeType` is a two-element tuple itself, you don't even need `into_tuple()`, just write `method2()` call as it is:

```
method2(a)
```

Tuples also provide [tuple indexing syntax](https://github.com/P1start/rfcs/blob/tuple-accessors/active/0000-tuple-accessors.md) for tuples and tuple structs instead of soon-to-be-deprecated [tuple traits](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/tuple/). It also can be used:

```
let res = method2(a);
(res.0, res.1)
```

It is redundant if `SomeType` is indeed a tuple of the same size, but if `SomeType` is a tuple of larger size, this is the way to go. Or you can use destructuring:

```
let (v1, v2, _) = method2(a);  // need as many placeholders as there are remaining elements in the tuple
(v1, v2)
```

Comment: `method2` returns a tuple `(String, String, .....)`, it can be seen from `res.val0()` and `res.val1()` method calls.

Comment: I suspected so, but no one prevents you from adding custom `val0()` and `val1()` methods to any datatype you want, as is perfectly demonstrated by @PaoloFalabella in his comment.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev I accidentally erased my comment. Playpen link again for reference http://is.gd/3ySXZi (not sure how long these live by the way...)

Comment: Da chtozh ya sovsem uzhe iz uma vizhil chtobi dobavlyat' metodi s takimi imenami?